# Xcode quits unexpectedly when I add the xcdatamodel to the project

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I am currently developing an iOS application for both iPhone and iPad. I recently merged my branch with another branch, and now I can't add the `.xcdatamodel` file because Xcode quit immediately.

The only way that remains open Xcode is if my project doesn't have an xcdatamodel. I attach a screenshot.

[image: xcdatamodel can't be loaded in the project if I want to remain open Xcode]

I don't know how to add my xcdatamodel without Xcode quit unexpectedly

Comment: To be more specific, I just discover that Xcode quits unexpectedly only when I try to open the current version of my xcdatamodel (Akdemia.xcdatamodel, that is mark with a green check in the screenshot). If I try to open any of the older versions Xcode works perfect.

Comment: I open file Akdemia.xcdatamodel/content using Sublime and I checked the code looking for any merge conflict but didn't found anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the error.

I deleted all the models that I created in Akdemia.xcdatamodel using Sublime, keeping only the changes from the merge, then Xcode accepted the xcdatamodel without closing and I created all my models again using Xcode.